# Windows Forms / C#: only one object instance out of many will paint

Tags: c#, windows, forms, object

Here's the problem:

I've been working on a little game where monsters bounce off the walls (edges) of the main form, and it's going swimmingly, but it only paints one of each type of monster when it should be iterating through a list of each of them and calling their OnPaint and Move methods:

```
private void Pacmen_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Rectangle rect = e.ClipRectangle;

    g.Clear(backgroundColor);

    foreach (Hydra h in hydraList) {
        h.OnPaint(e);
        h.Move(e);
    } // end foreach

    foreach (Ghost gh in ghostList) {
        gh.OnPaint(e);
        gh.Move(e);
    } // end foreach
}
```

Here's the ghost's methods:

```
public void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    SolidBrush fillBrush = new SolidBrush(color);
    SolidBrush eyeBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    path.AddArc(pos, (float)180, (float)180);
    path.AddLine((float)pos.Right, (float)(pos.Y + pos.Height / 2),
        (float)pos.Right, (float)pos.Bottom);
    path.AddLine((float)pos.Right, (float)pos.Bottom,
        (float)(pos.X + pos.Width / 2), (float)(pos.Bottom - radius / 2));
    path.AddLine((float)(pos.X + pos.Width / 2), (float)(pos.Bottom - radius / 2),
        (float)pos.Left, (float)pos.Bottom);
    path.AddLine((float)pos.Left, (float)pos.Bottom,
        (float)pos.Left, (float)(pos.Y + pos.Height / 2));

    g.FillPath(fillBrush, path);
    g.FillEllipse(eyeBrush, new Rectangle(pos.X + pos.Width / 4, pos.Y + pos.Height / 4, radius / 4, radius / 5));
    g.FillEllipse(eyeBrush, new Rectangle(pos.X + 3 * pos.Width / 4, pos.Y + pos.Height / 4, radius / 4, radius / 5));
} // end OnPaint

public void Move(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    pos.Offset(xSpeed, ySpeed);
}
```

Any ideas why only one would show up? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is worth an answer but you should really cache the SolidBrushes between calls to OnPaint - store them in the class somewhere. Also they do need to be disposed.

Comment: ...and you should not be recreating the path over and over either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're giving the characters individual starting positions and speed? Maybe they are all painting, but on exactly the same spot?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `OnPaint` for each hydra and ghost by using the same `PaintEventArgs` passed to `Pacmen_Paint`. Maybe the `OnPaint` methods are not using the correct `Graphics` object then.

Comment: I presume that `Pacmen_Paint` is the actual `Paint` event handler, so `Graphics` instance looks like the right one to use for all drawing.

Comment: Ok, I was assuming that every monster had its own Graphics object.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the body of your `Ghost` method with simple:

```
Console.WriteLine("Ghost at " +  pos.X + ", " + pos.Y);
```

Then run the app and check the Output window in VS to see where they are drawn exactly.

Other notes (others may have commented already):

1. [Use the `using` construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx) to dispose Brushes and other disposable graphics objects inside the `Paint` method, or cache them and make your `Ghost` and `Hydra` objects [implement `IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28VS.80%29.aspx) to dispose them when they are not needed anymore.
2. You may get some speed improvements if you simply create a `Bitmap` field containg an already drawn ghost, and then simply draw it inside `Paint`. That way you only need to create your graphic objects once (inside `using` construct, again).

Comment: Thanks, turns out they were drawing on top of each other... and I thought they were all random.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. You should also consider about other remarks to make your app work faster and use less memory.